# Calling a c++ virtual function from WndProc fails

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, virtual-functions

I'm developing a program that displays graphical windows using the windows API. Below is function I provided as the WndProc when registering the window class - it is a static function inside the class `WindowsWindow`.

```
#define BTK_DLL_FUNC __dllspec(dllexport)

class AbstractBackend
{
protected:
  bool FatalWarnings;

public:
  AbstractBackend (bool FatalWarnings=false);
  ~AbstractBackend ();

  virtual void StartMainLoop () = 0;
  virtual void QuitMainLoop () = 0;
};

class WindowsBackend : public Base::AbstractBackend
{
public:
  static HINSTANCE hinstance;
  static WindowsBackend* instance;

public:
  BTK_DLL_FUNC WindowsBackend ();
  BTK_DLL_FUNC ~WindowsBackend ();

  BTK_DLL_FUNC void StartMainLoop ();
  BTK_DLL_FUNC void QuitMainLoop ();
};


void WindowsBackend::StartMainLoop ()
{
  MSG Msg;
  while (GetMessage (&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
  {
    TranslateMessage (&Msg);
    DispatchMessage (&Msg);
  }
}

void WindowsBackend::QuitMainLoop ()
{
  PostQuitMessage (0); /* Send a WM_QUIT message, to stop the main loop */
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowsWindow::WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (msg)
  {
  case WM_CREATE:
    break;

  case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow (hwnd);
    break;

  case WM_DESTROY: /* The window was destroyed */
    {
      WindowsBackend::instance->QuitMainLoop (); /* This doesn't work! */
      break;
    }

  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now, here is the part I don't understand - The QuitMainLoop doesn't begin and it doesn't return (I tried the debugger and it showed that the Quit function isn't being called, and also that any line after that call isn't being executed). So practically, my program gets stuck after that call.

But, replacing the call to the custom quit function with a direct call to `PostQuitMessage` works.

Any explanations and/or way to get around this (and be able to call a virtual function) would be highly appriciated.

Edit: Added the exact code

Comment: I can't believe that this is your real code.

Comment: It isn't my "full" real code, but it does cause the bug. I narrowed my code and removed parts untill I found only the lines of code that still cause a problem. My real code also includes handing of many other cases in the WndProc, and also some freeing of resources after posting the quit message.

Comment: You've stripped too much code, it is hard to believe that B doesn't inherit A for example.  It is also quite strange to create a *new* object of type B when the intention is to quit the *current* instance of the program.  The code just doesn't make enough sense to diagnose the real problem.

Comment: Sorry all. Added the exact code. Apparently I did strip too much :(

Comment: Mmmh is the __dllspec(dllexport) conflicting with the Virtual?

Comment: xanatos: Somehow I doubt that, since it works fine when I call StartMainLoop() on the instance of the WindowsBackend to start the entire thing.

Comment: Here it works correctly (I'm using VS 2010). What compiler are you using? Mingw?

Comment: xanatos: Visual Studio 2010 :( And that is indeed the full code

Comment: Try adding a `MessageBox(NULL, _T("Hello"), _T("Hello"), 0);` in the `QuitMainLoop`, then rebuild everything and hope :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3130/discussion-between-lightningismyname-and-xanatos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not posted full code that we can run to reproduce the problem we have to guess.

The only way that I can see for the call to `QuitMainLoop()` to fail is if `WindowsBackend::instance` is somehow corrupted. Have you destroyed it by mistake before calling `QuitMainLoop()`? Has there been a memory corruption perhaps?

I would look at this under the disassembly view in the debugger. That should tell you what has gone wrong and then you need to follow the clues to find out why.

Comment: The instance was indeed corrupted - this solved the problem. Thanks